# groovy input into file iterate over map

Tags: groovy

Hi I got the map and loop iterate over the map.

```
def map = [file.txt : file2.txt,
file3.txt : fil4.txt,
file5.txt : file6.txt]

map.each { k,v ->
 collection = new file("k").readLines()
 collection2 = new file("v").readLines.findResult() 

def commons = collection.intersect(collection2)

}
```

I want every "commons" collection save into a file, not overwriting this file over the next iterations.

Is there a possibility to do such a thing in the loop?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick my first idea was "new file("path/to/file").write(commons)", then "new file("path/to/file").withWriter(commons)".
and I don't know how to handle this

Comment: @rupert, show examples - what do you have in file1 - file4 and what do you expect in output file.

Comment: @daggett files from 1 to 6, are just simple files with text, and I want to read lines from files and show commons. My script is working, but I don't know how to save my result which is collection "commons" into file for e.g. result.txt

Comment: your question does not correspond to what you are asking now... use something simple: [new File(path),append(text)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#append(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already have your list of files to merge, then the only thing you need to do is to write the lines of each file into the output file, you can do something like this:

```
def files = ['file1.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file2.txt']
def file = new File('output.txt')
def outputFile = file.newPrintWriter()

def mergeFile = { fileName ->   
    File sourceFile = new File(fileName) 
    sourceFile.eachLine{ line ->
        outputFile.println(line)
    }
}

files.each(mergeFile)

out.close()
```

This will merge the contents of all your files, there is another thing, you may need to specify the folder of the files, so I suggest to use the constructor that receives the folder.

```
File output = new File(folder, filename)
```